# Data Fitting and Prediction in Machine learning models

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

In classification or Regression we need our model to learn from the input data(Training Data). Like for Example, finding best possible model parameter value (in linear Regression).

While I was going through Classification Part in machine learning I met this code given below(a model to classify "Not-5" in MNIST Dataset):

This code is from [Github-Aurelien Geron](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml) handson-ml-master/03_Classification.ipynb

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
class Never5Classifier(BaseEstimator):
def fit(self, X, y=None): # fit the data
    pass
def predict(self, X):
    print(X.shape)
    print(len(X))
    return np.zeros((len(X), 1), dtype=bool)
```

And below is the code to perform Cross validation on the model.

```
never_5_clf = Never5Classifier()

cross_val_score(never_5_clf, X_train, y_train_5, cv=3, scoring="accuracy")
```

Well this is custom made model and so I want to know that how data is fitted (what Happens inside the black box). Although I came across many models, but there were some mathematical proof/way to determine the parameter value.

Comment: Where did you find this code? Please link that.

Comment: @VivekKumar Done!

Comment: The never5classifier dont learn anything and always predict all data to be negative. i.e. not 5.

Answer (score 0):

In the above example you gave here, your model is trying to classify whether or not a specific figure from your dataset is labeled as the number `5`. This is done by feeding your model with a `training set` containing only the number `5`, from this `training set`, your model is learning what are the characteristics (`features`), that are unique for the figure `5`. This way, your model is learning from the 28x28 pixels each image in your `training set` contains. After you finished training your model (feeding enough samples of the digit `5` to your classifier), your model is now ready for testing. In the testing stage, you are using a `testing set`, which in this case, will be different from the `training set` your model learned from. It will be different in a way that it won't only contain the digit `5` like in the `training set`, but now it will contain all types of digits (`0-9`), and your model will able to classify each sample with either 1 which means `true` (aka it is a `5`), or with a `0` which is `false` (aka it is not a `5`). This is the way the `fit()` function is working in this case, you are training your model with only one digit (in your case it is the number `5`), and afterwards you are testing whether or not your model is able to see if a random digit from the `testing set` is actually `5` or other digit. After calling `fit()` on your `training set`, your model has learned to recognize the digit `5`, but it didn't learn how does `3, 8, 4 or 1` looks like, but it can know that if it not `5`, than it is another number which the model haven't learned yet.